# paypal subscription method without the buttons - Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, paypal

I am making a payment checkout where i am implementing paypal. I rendered the paypal buttons using their methods, but i want to place the actions of those buttons on my custom button and it not working.

I tried to change the function but it didnt work.

Here is the function to render the buttons and do the checkout action :

```
paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'subscribe'
      },
      createSubscription(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          /* Creates the subscription */
          plan_id: 'My ID hiden'
        });
      },
      onApprove(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
      }
    }).render(this.paypalElement2.nativeElement);
```

I tried to make this:

```
checkout() {
   paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription(data, actions) {
          return actions.subscription.create({
            /* Creates the subscription */
            plan_id: ''
          });
        },
        onApprove(data, actions) {
          alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
        }
      });

}
```

But when i press the button nothing happens.

Is there a way to makie this work?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to place the actions of those buttons on my custom button

This **cannot** be done with the PayPal JavaScript, `paypal.Buttons(...)`

If you want to use your own button to directly start the checkout, you need to integrate only with the PayPal REST API (no JS SDK) and redirect to the `approve` href returned when you create a subscription via API.  This is not recommended, since it obviously involves redirecting away from your site.  Using the PayPal JS buttons is superior since it keeps your site loaded in the background and opens a small window for the payment approval.